# XSL transform namespace weirdness

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a generated XML file that looks like the following:

```
<PublishFACSR xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2015-07-14T09:23:24-06:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1436887397443667260" maximoVersion="7 5 20140411-2000 V7511--1" event="1">
  <FACSRSet>
    <SR action="Replace">
      <ACCUMULATEDHOLDTIME>0.0</ACCUMULATEDHOLDTIME>
      <ACTLABCOST>0.0</ACTLABCOST>
      <ACTLABHRS>0.0</ACTLABHRS>
      <TICKETID>SR-35102</TICKETID>
      <TICKETUID>39822</TICKETUID>
      <URGENCY changed="1">3</URGENCY>
      <VENDOR />
      <VIRTUALENV>0</VIRTUALENV>
    </SR>
  </FACSRSet>
</PublishFACSR>
```

I need to replace:
 PublishFACSR with SyncFACSR
 SR action="Replace"  with  SR action="AddChange"

I tried using the following XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- This template copies everything that doesn't have a more specific rule -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- This template copies and renames PublishMXASSET to SyncMXASSSET -->
<xsl:template match="PublishMXASSET">
  <SyncMXASSSET>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </SyncMXASSSET>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it generated the following output:

```
<SyncFACSR creationDateTime="2015-07-14T12:34:19-06:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1436898852543140608" maximoVersion="7 5 20140411-2000 V7511--1" event="1">
  <FACSRSet xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SR action="Replace">
      <ACCUMULATEDHOLDTIME>0.0</ACCUMULATEDHOLDTIME>
      <ACTLABCOST>0.0</ACTLABCOST>
      <ACTLABHRS>0.0</ACTLABHRS>
      <TICKETID>SR-35102</TICKETID>
      <TICKETUID>39822</TICKETUID>
      <URGENCY>3</URGENCY>
      <VENDOR />
      <VIRTUALENV>0</VIRTUALENV>
    </SR>
  </FACSRSet>
</SyncFACSR>
```

The biggest problem is that the namespaces have been moved down to the FACSRSet.  I assume this is something with the order in which the XML is being generated and the XSL applied.

The output should look like the following:

```
<SyncFACSR  xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2015-07-14T12:34:19-06:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1436898852543140608" maximoVersion="7 5 20140411-2000 V7511--1" event="1">
  <FACSRSet>
    <SR action="Replace">
      <ACCUMULATEDHOLDTIME>0.0</ACCUMULATEDHOLDTIME>
      <ACTLABCOST>0.0</ACTLABCOST>
      <ACTLABHRS>0.0</ACTLABHRS>
      <TICKETID>SR-35102</TICKETID>
      <TICKETUID>39822</TICKETUID>
      <URGENCY>3</URGENCY>
      <VENDOR />
      <VIRTUALENV>0</VIRTUALENV>
    </SR>
  </FACSRSet>
</SyncFACSR>
```

Any ideas on how to resolve.

Oh, and fix the action="AddChange"

thanks

Comment: "*it generated the following output*"  No, I don't think it did. Please post a **complete** example of your input - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Complete example posted.  thank you

Comment: If you want to replace `PublishFACSR` with `SyncFACSR` then make your template `match="mx:PublishFACSR'` - where 'mx' is a prefix that you have bound to the `"http://www.ibm.com/maximo"` namespace. -- You have not posted your output, and it's not clear in what namespace the new node `SyncFACSR` should be.

Comment: I posted both the output I get, and the output I expect. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the XSLT that you show us does **not** produce the output that you say it does.

Next, the "biggest problem" with the output that you claim is **not** what you say it is:

> The biggest problem is that the namespaces have been moved down to the
>   FACSRSet.

Actually, that's not a problem at all: a namespace declaration can appear anywhere - as long as it's not used outside the scope of the declaring element.

The **real** problem with your output is that the `SyncFACSR` element is in no-namespace, while your expected output places it in the `"http://www.ibm.com/maximo"` namespace - same as the `PublishFACSR` element that it replaces and all its descendants.

To achieve the expected result, your stylesheet should do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
xsl:exclude-result-prefixes="max">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="max:PublishFACSR" >
    <SyncMXASSSET xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </SyncMXASSSET>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally,  to replace SR action="Replace" with SR action="AddChange", add another template:

```
<xsl:template match="max:SR/@action[.='Replace']" >
    <xsl:attribute name="action">AddChange</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ok, i took another look, I think I misunderstood what you were saying. I did post an error in my original posting.., I am going to post the answer that did work for me.

Comment: @flyingpie "*I am going to post the answer that did work for me.*"  There is no need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So, following michael.hor257k's advice. here is the XSL that worked to transform my XML

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ibm ="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:template match="ibm:PublishFACSR">
    <SyncFACSR xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </SyncFACSR>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- exception-->
  <xsl:template match="ibm:SR/@action[.='Replace']" >
    <xsl:attribute name="action">AddChange</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for all the help