# Using XSL to replace a portion of text in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use XSL to replace a portion of text.
The XSL is also doing 2 other things and they are working fine.

Here is the source XML

```
<PublishFACSR xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2015-07-14T09:23:24-06:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1436887397443667260" maximoVersion="7 5 20140411-2000 V7511--1" event="1">
  <FACSRSet>
    <SR action="Replace">
      <TICKETID>SR-35102</TICKETID>
    </SR>
  </FACSRSet>
</PublishFACSR>
```

Here is the XSL i am trying, my problem is the last section. I simply need to change the text in TICKETID from SR-35102  to  EX-35102

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ibm ="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:template match="ibm:PublishFACSR">
    <SyncFACSR xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </SyncFACSR>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- exception-->
  <xsl:template match="ibm:SR/@action[.='Replace']" >
    <xsl:attribute name="action">AddChange</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
<!-- Substitute the SR on <ticketid> with EX -->
  <xsl:template match="TICKETID">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat('EX', substring-after( @TICKETID, 'SR'))"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you not learned from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414928/xsl-transform-namespace-weirdness) that the elements in your XMl are in a namespace and need to be addressed using a prefix?

In the same way that you use:

```
<xsl:template match="ibm:PublishFACSR">
```

and:

```
<xsl:template match="ibm:SR/@action[.='Replace']" >
```

you must also make your new template:

```
<xsl:template match="ibm:TICKETID">
```

otherwise it will not match anything and not do anything.

Once you have fixed that, you need to replace the reference to a non-existing attribute `@TICKETID` with a reference to the current node:

```
substring-after(., 'SR')
```

instead of:

```
substring-after( @TICKETID, 'SR')
```

Finally, remove the `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` instruction - otherwise the original text will be appended to the corrected one.